# Is mixing 'Adsense' banners and content okay on a Pinterest style layout?

Tags: google-adsense

I was under the impression that Google likes to have their adverts clearly separated out from content so that people don't accidentally click on the adverts thinking they are articles.

For a 'pinterest' style layout where you only see the one page and a few pop ups over that one page, you could mix in the adverts with the content, as demonstrated with the two adverts slap in the middle on this site:

[image]

Clearly this can be done and it exists in the wild, with Google adverts being supplied to the site.

However, is that against the spirit and/or the letter of what one signs up to with Adsense?

Answer (score 1):

This implementation appears quite similar to the 'Aligning images with ads' implementation described [here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en&ref_topic=1271508&rd=1#Aligning_images_with_ads).

> Publishers may not attempt to associate specific images with the
>   individual ads appearing on their sites. Such an implementation may
>   confuse users who assume that the image is directly related to the
>   advertiser's offerings and therefore is a violation of our program
>   policies.

[image]

Also, as far as I know Adsense should be used only on pages having substantial content. The pinterest style page doesn't have any content It is just a collection of images and links.

So, using Adsense only on article pages and not the article listing pages is recommened.